# Can Neo 4j be integrated with HDFS/Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, neo4j, cypher, hdfs

Can Neo 4j be integrated with HDFS/Hadoop? Mostly using Hadoop to increase the processing capabilities of Neo 4j, when working on large datasets involving many relations and having large amount of transactions per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very broad question. Maybe consider to provide more context. Since the question is general my reply cannot be very specific.

A lot of people out there use hadoop (or similar tooling) to preprocess data and store the results into Neo4j. Maybe check out some blog post on this, e.g. http://blog.xebia.com/2012/11/13/combining-neo4j-and-hadoop-part-i/ and http://blog.xebia.com/2013/01/17/combining-neo4j-and-hadoop-part-ii/. There's more material on the web, just use your favorite search engine....